# jquery .text() == not working

Tags: jquery

I have this code here:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
                var counter = 0;
                if($(this).text() == 'About Us'){
                        console.log('here');
                }
        });
```

but its not working, I don't see the 'here' in my console.

When I do console.log for the text I can see the text 'About Us' What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: i did...it says About Us

Comment: Try [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) or [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) before comparing. The `.text()` may include surrounding whitespace from the markup.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i just saw that. my second guess is that since you're clicking on an `<a>`, it's probably doing something else. try adding `e.PreventDefault()`

Comment: Can you also include the relevant markup in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that there might be some leading or trailing whitespaces with the text so use `trim()` to remove extra whitespaces:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
                var counter = 0;
                if($(this).text().trim() == 'About Us'){
                        console.log('here');
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have white spaces etc so you need to `.trim` it which will take these invalid parts out for you.

try this.

```
$('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {
                    var counter = 0;
                    var trim = $(this).text().trim();
                    if(trim == 'About Us'){
                        console.log('here');
                    }
            });
```